# Javascript: Objects Contains 100% Across Dates

Tags: javascript, date, comparison, ecmascript-5

You are given a start date and an end date. The last object's end date can be empty, but every preceding object's end date must contain a value (if end date is empty, end date stretches to infinity). The percent must be 100% across the dates given. Assume objects are ordered by start dates (earliest to latest).

Using a start date of 2021-01 and an end date of 2021-05. If there is a gap between the objects' dates, then return false. Example: Object C's start date and end date is from 04 to 05 months, then there is a gap in March [03]

Using a start date of 2021-01 and an end date of 2021-05. If the percentages are less than 100 at a specific date range, then there should be an object that covers the rest of the percentages. Otherwise, return false. Example: Object C's percent is 50, then there should be an Object that covers another 50% (Object D with the same start and end dates).

I'm using ES5 as my application doesn't run any later versions. My attempt where I'm using a function to get parameters of start date, end date, and list of objects

```
// Example of a list of objects. Can be an empty list.
var list = [
    {'percent':'100', 'start':'2021-01', 'end':'2021-02'}, // A
    {'percent':'100', 'start':'2021-02', 'end':'2021-03'}, // B
    {'percent':'100', 'start':'2021-03', 'end':'2021-05'}  // C
]

function hasHundredAcrossDates(sd, ed, list) {
    if (list.length == 0) { // because you are given a date range, there must be an object with 100%
        return false;
    }
    if (sd != start) { // must begin at the same date
        return false;
    }
    
    var p = 0;
    var start = '';
    var end = '';
    for (var key in list) {
        //TODO: not sure how to compare the dates given the percentages
    }
}
```

Looking for advice on how to get started on the logic piece as I'm not sure on this part. Thanks!

Comment: You might start by looping over the array elements and checking if `obj[i].end == obj[i + 1].start`, stopping when `i == array.length - 2`, since you don't care about the end date of the last element.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I don't think this would work since if the "percent" is less than 100, there must be dates to cover the missing percent

Comment: So there are two questions: checking that there is no gap in the date ranges and ensuring there is 100% coverage for each range. The sample data objects all have 100%.